# fsolve in Maple for solving a system of equations

Tags: maple

I have a system of 8 equations and 8 unknowns. There is nothing numerical in these set of equations. All there is in the equations is parameters; 8 of these parameters are my unknown variables (hereafter, unknown variables), which I'm solving for, and there are a bunch of other parameters, that are NOT unknown values, such as alpha, beta, gamma (hereafter, parameters).

I need to solve the system of equations, such that I get the 8 unknown variables in terms of parameters.

I used fsolve([equations],[variables]) in Maple. However, it returns an error that says tau, alpha, beta, ... are in the equations and are not solved for. How can I make Maple to understand that these are not variables that I like to solve for, but they are just parameters that the rest of unknown variables should be solved in terms of?

Here is an example of one of my equations:

```
e1 := (L__af+L__mf)/(1-tau) = `A__a,star`*L__ah^(1-alpha)*`L__ah,star`^alpha/A__a+`A__m,star`*L__mh^(1-alpha)*`L__mh,star`^alpha/A__m
```

in which all `L`'s are unknown variables and anything else should be treated as a known parameter.

Answer (score 1):

fsolve is for doing numerical solutions as opposed to symbolic.  For a numerical solution, your values for the known variables have to have a numerical value assigned to them.  If you want a symbolic solution, try solve({equations},{variables}).  If it can't find a solution, then try fsolve, but with specific values for those variables.